# How to compare two Terraform plans for differences?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

There is a pipeline that generates a Terraform plan and pauses until a manager approves the changes. It can pass an undetermined period of time for it to be approved (one second, three hours, etc) so the proposed Terraform plan could differ from the Terraform plan executed after the approval due to many reasons like the infrastructure being manually modified (not intended but possible).

The pipeline after the approval runs the second Terraform plan and compares it with the first one generated in the pre-approval stage. The pipeline does the comparison with a git diff and fails if there is a difference. That is not working as expected because the plans differ even if generated one after the other, in a section called relevant_attributes, but the differences are the order in which the JSON is generated, not the content or effective changes.
[image]

The following scripts are being used to generate the JSONs and compare them out:

```
terraform show -json expected.tfplan | jq . > expected.json
terraform show -json actual.tfplan | jq . > actual.json
git diff --no-index expected.json actual.json || exit 1
```

Is there a fix for this approach? Alternatively, are there better ways to compare two Terraform plans for differences in this approval scenario?

Comment: Depending on what you are using, you could maybe try Terraform Cloud.

Comment: If you are executing Terraform within a pipeline, then normally the plan is output and applied in a subsequent stage post-approval. That would also avoid this issue about comparing the plans.

Comment: Yes, the output is the plan but the approval usually takes time, and in between the infra could change due to manual modifications, maybe someone was testing something and forgot to undo it, or someone with access to the resources didn't know about the pipeline that had to be used to change the infra in the team of 25 people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your plan with [`-out=PLAN_FILE`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#out-filename) and then only apply it when you want.

For example, you can run

```
terraform plan -out tfplan.zip
```

To show the plan you can run

```
terraform show tfplan.zip
```

Then when you want to apply you just run [`terraform apply PLAN_FILE`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/apply#saved-plan-mode)

```
terraform apply tfplan.zip
```

---

Or you can go for other approaches, for example by using approval features on some CI/CD platforms ([circleci](https://circleci.com/blog/adding-approval-jobs-to-your-ci-pipeline/), or [GitHub Actions's deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/about-deployments/deploying-with-github-actions) for example) where you block the apply step and keep your pipeline pending.

Or simply treat your IaC as we would treat our code, only deploy when merging to some branches; makes your `main` branches protected and only require approvals from authorized people. When opening a PR run a simple Terraform plan, and when it gets merged you run `terraform apply`.

---

Edit:

Apparently, these solutions might not fit your use case, so your approach might be better, you just need to sort your `resource_change` array with `jq` in case it gets shuffled between each plan

```
 terraform show -json expected.tfplan | jq '.resource_changes | sort_by(.address)'
```

Comment: We were doing that but the infra could change since the plan is generated to when it is going to be applied causing unintentional problems. So to inform what were the exact changes, the diff is a proposed solution that has this problem of non-important differences.

Comment: I didn't quite get your issue, if you fully manage your infra with Terraform you can get around that configuration drift between the plans & reality by only using terraform to manage it, for the IaC you can use a proper git branching model where you deploy when merging to a `main`/`release` branch

Comment: Or, if you want to continue editing the infrastructure manually AND keep using terraform you may want to consider set [`-refresh=false`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#refresh-false) or something. Also if your plan that requires these approvals covers a subset of resources, consider breaking down your IaC into multiple workspaces or repositories. Or, am I misunderstanding what you want to achieve?

Comment: The infra could change due to manual modifications, maybe someone was testing something and forgot to undo it, or someone with access to the resources didn't know about the pipeline that had to be used to change the infra in the team of 25 people. I'm considering just to compare the resource_changes array from the Terraform plan, do you think is a good idea? Or could the order of their elements change? In my tests, they don't.

Comment: I don't know if the order of `resource_change` elements can change. However, I would sort it anyways before I compare, you can use jq for that like: `cat file | jq '.resource_changes | sort_by(.SOME_FIELD)'`, or just the address: `cat file | jq '.resource_changes | sort_by(.address)'`

Comment: Sure thing :) I edited this answer for more visibility in case someone else has the same use-case